# MySQL 8- Add a Default Partition to a Table Partitioned on a Field Value

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table partitioned by values of a KPI field. There are some kpi with a large amount of rows some with small numbers. Partitioning by KPI name (string) keeps query performance good.

The data source occasionally will introduce a new KpI which breaks the loader. The file being uploaded that contains the new kpi value will fail.

I want to add a default partition to cover these conditions.

After searching around I found and tried this command

alter table X add partition (partition pDefault values in (DEFAULT));

MySQL workbench doesn’t like this command highlighting the second to last ‘)’ saying it is not valid at this position, expecting ‘(‘.

I’ve looked through MySQL help index and googled for an hour but can’t find what is wrong with this or another way to do what I want to do.

Ideas?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must list explicit values when using LIST partitioning. You can't make a "default" or "catch-all" partition for values you didn't list.

This is documented:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-list.html says:

> Unlike the case with `RANGE` partitioning, there is no “catch-all” such as `MAXVALUE`; all expected values for the partitioning expression should be covered in `PARTITION ... VALUES IN (...)` clauses. An `INSERT` statement containing an unmatched partitioning column value fails with an error.

Comment: Thanks Bill. As mentioned in my other comment we got what we needed out list partitioning. My team does control new kpi values and they are few. I'll just manage it manually if/when it happens.

Answer (score 2):

`PARTITIONing` rarely helps with performance.  If your queries are usually

```
WHERE ...
  AND kpi = 'asdf'
```

then performance may be *improved* by getting rid of partitioning and adding *composite* index(es) that *start with* `kpi`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the main queries.  With them, we can provide more specific advice.

As mentioned by Bill, `PARTITION BY LIST` is a maintenance nightmare if the list changes.  I see no good use for it.

Comment: A good use for list partitioning is if you want to drop a specific partition quickly. I agree that using partitioning for performance is no better than using indexes in most cases, and indexes are more flexible.

Comment: I was using indexes  but couldn't get to the performance we wanted. When I partitioned by list the performance improved dramatically. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @user22668153 - Did you have `INDEX(kpi, something_else)`?  What was the `WHERE` clause in the query?